# How to raise a number to a power of 1/n in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, pow, arithmetic-expressions

I just want to raise a number to the power of 1/n. If I do this way: 2**(1/7), I alway get 1, regardless of n; and this only ocurrs when the dividen is 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `2 ** (1.0 / 7)` to avoid integer division

Comment: Ruby has a [`Rational`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Rational.html) class: `2 ** (1/7r)`

Comment: @Stefan's comment should be the correct answer. It is better than the accepted one.

Comment: @sawa not sure if this is more correct – the result is a float either way, e.g. `9 ** (1/2r)` returns `3.0`, not `3` or `(3/1)`

Comment: @Stefan I think that is expected. That is because the 1/n-th power is not rational in general. But I think the OP's intention of writing 1/7 was 1/7 as a rational number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `1/7` in a console and see what you get.

Then try `1.0 / 7.0`, to avoid "integer division."